# Is there any way to ftp into wordpress if I paid for my own domain? I want to set up google analytics

Tags: ftp, google-analytics

I am quite confused. I have my own host for wordpress that I paid for, and I want to be able to ftp into my files to manually edit them. I know wordpress does not support or allow ftp, but I see a lot of people doing it on privately hosted domains:

[Here is an example that assumes you can ftp in](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-google-analytics-in-wordpress/)

I am trying to use FireFTP to do this, but I have been unsuccessful.

Please let me know if this is possible, I really want google analytics :)

Thanks,

tylerthemiler

Comment: wordpress.com  ≠ wordprss.org

Comment: Define "your own host" ? What exactly you paid for and to which company?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **self-hosted WordPress**, i.e. that you *downloaded yourself* via **wordpress.org**, and **installed yourself** on the *server account* provided by your *hosting provider*, then: yes; you can FTP into your WordPress installation (and in fact, almost *have* to do so, in order to install it).

If you are using the **hosted blogging service wordpress.COM**, then: no, you *cannot* FTP into your account, regardless of whether you have purchased a domain that maps to your wordpress.com account. In this case, you're still using the hosted service from wordpress.com.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your hosting provider. Ask them for your FTP account log-in info. Take the info they give you and log-into the FTP. Next go to [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), add your site. Next go to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue=http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue%253D/addurl&followup=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue=http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue%253D/addurl&authuser=0) and submit your site. If you have any questions along the way stack exchange has several help sections available and so does Google.